# android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner Class Not Found

Tags: android, android-testing

When trying to run an android test case I get the following last two lines:

```
[2013-04-22 17:11:10 - ProjectTest] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on emulator-5554
[2013-04-22 17:11:12 - ProjectTest] Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'
```

I believe I need to include a jar into my build path. Any idea of which jar I need to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should have researched bit on internet or searched on Stackoverflow. There is a similar problem statement in the Stackoverflow: [Test run failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16046474/test-run-failed-instrumentation-run-failed-due-to-java-lang-classnotfoundexcep)

Comment: That is a prevoius post of mine, where I answered the issue I had at the time... I seem to be having the issue again, but looks like it may be based on something else...

Comment: looks like I goofed... was the same issue :( Following my directions in the other post I solved the issue... I'll accept ur answer and then delete this question.